# Удаление символов из строки python

Tags: python

Есть список `[('kkkkk',)]`, никак не могу понять как удалить символы `[(,)]`, то есть чтобы осталось только `kkkkk`

Comment: у вас это строка? или вам просто `print(x[0][0])` надо сделать?

Answer (score 1):

`[('kkkkk',)]` -- это не строка, а список (обозначается квадратными скобками), в котором находится кортеж (обозначается круглыми скобками, а также запятой в конце), в котором находится строка "kkkkk". Чтобы получить строку из этого, вам нужно обратиться по индексу к кортежу и, внутри него, к строке:

```
>>> a = [('kkkkk',)]
>>> a[0][0]
'kkkkk'
```

Comment: точно, спасибо огромное

Comment: Главное в кортеже - это не круглые скобки, а запятая! С запятой и без скобок кортеж возможен, а вот со скобками и без запятой кортежа не будет )  В общем, добавьте про запятую обязательно как признак кортежа